# How can I grep these lines

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I want to grep lines starting with a `@` and also lines starting with `//` followed by a line starting with `@`

Example:

```
//text1
@text2
text3
```

result:

```
//text1
@text2
```

How can I do this with grep or any other basic unix tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print( $z . $_ ) if m{^\@}; $z=(m{^//} ? $_ : "");'
```

This one-liner processes STDIN one line at a time.

If a line beginning with `@` is found it dumps the contents of `$z` followed by the current line.

Then, if it detects a line beginning with `//` it saves the line in a variable `$z`. The `$z` variable is cleared if the line does *not* start with `//`.

I have given this a quick test and should do the job requested.

The `grep` tool does not remember state between lines.